# IntelliJ Have Safe Delete on by default

Tags: intellij-idea, automated-refactoring, intellij-14

In older versions of IntelliJ I remember that Safe Delete was always activated by default, or at least it remembered the last state that I left it in. Now in Intellij 14.0.2, whenever I go to delete, when I'm prompted whether I want to execute Safe Delete, the **Safe Delete**, **Search in comments and strings**, and **Search for text occurrences** check boxes are always unchecked and I have to go check them again ever time that I delete. Is there some way that I can change this?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like some regression. You should report it as a bug on youtrack.jetbrains.com. In the meanwhile, here is a possible workaround:

There is a *Safe delete* action in *Settings/Keymap* which is mapped to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>DELETE</kbd> on Mac) by default. You can use this shortcut (or remap it to something else) for invoking safe delete directly.

When you invoke the Safe delete dialog using this action there are two checkboxes (Search in comments and strings, Search for text occurences). Those are not checked by default, but when you invoke the Safe delete action again, IntelliJ remembers the previous options (which is another reason to think that the behavior for the normal delete dialog is a bug).

[image]

Give it a try

Comment: Thanks. That does work well. I may just be mis-remembering. I'm getting old, especially old for a programmer. Looks like it's Command-Delete on a Mac. I should've been able to have figured this out! Sigh.

Comment: It's a bug. On the Mac build at least, calling Safe Delete using Command-Delete also does not remember the previous check boxes which is my primary gripe. I filed https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-135022 which looks like they'll be fixing